# Can't find the recaptcha button with selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to solve a recapture with selenium by finding it and clicking on it (still not represented in the code) but I can't even find it in the page even though it is presented there. here is my code:

def capthcha(url = "https://google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo"):

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
delay = 5

try:
    captcha = WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'recaptcha-checkbox-border'))
    )

    print("Captcha is present in the DOM \n\n")
except TimeoutException:

    print("Captcha did not show up\n\n")


soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
print(soup)
```

I'm getting an output but I can't find here the recapture button:

Captcha did not show up

```
<html dir="ltr"><head><meta content="Az520Inasey3TAyqLyojQa8MnmCALSEU29yQFW8dePZ7xQTvSt73pHazLFTK5f7SyLUJSo2uKLesEtEa9aUYcgMAAACPeyJvcmlnaW4iOiJodHRwczovL2dvb2dsZS5jb206NDQzIiwiZmVhdHVyZSI6IkRpc2FibGVUaGlyZFBhcnR5U3RvcmFnZVBhcnRpdGlvbmluZyIsImV4cGlyeSI6MTcyNTQwNzk5OSwiaXNTdWJkb21haW4iOnRydWUsImlzVGhpcmRQYXJ0eSI6dHJ1ZX0=" http-equiv="origin-trial"/><meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="content-type"/><meta content="IE=edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"/><meta content="width=device-width, user-scalable=yes" name="viewport"/><title>ReCAPTCHA demo</title><link href="https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/releases/MydHw_zggsxIJuhSbyOmPv5R/demo__ltr.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/><script async="" crossorigin="anonymous" integrity="sha384-LzEnReQQed5ol5AFwl71PUw/lqyIcw22944Y6TAegcKGwBmgeJYXjB2CbgaSwp8z" nonce="" src="https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/releases/MydHw_zggsxIJuhSbyOmPv5R/recaptcha__en.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script async="" defer="" nonce="" src="/recaptcha/api.js"></script></head><body><div class="sample-form"><form id="recaptcha-demo-form" method="POST"><fieldset><legend>Sample Form with ReCAPTCHA</legend><ul><li><label for="input1">First Name</label><input aria-disabled="true" class="jfk-textinput" disabled="" id="input1" name="input1" type="text" value="Jane"/></li><li><label for="input2">Last Name</label><input aria-disabled="true" class="jfk-textinput" disabled="" id="input2" name="input2" type="text" value="Smith"/></li><li><label for="input3">Email</label><input aria-disabled="true" class="jfk-textinput" disabled="" id="input3" name="input3" type="text" value="stopallbots@gmail.com"/></li><li><p>Pick your favorite color:</p><label class="jfk-radiobutton-label" for="option1"><input aria-checked="true" aria-disabled="true" checked="" class="jfk-radiobutton-checked" disabled="" id="option1" name="radios" type="radio" value="option1"/>Red</label><label class="jfk-radiobutton-label" for="option2"><input aria-disabled="true" class="jfk-radiobutton" disabled="" id="option2" name="radios" type="radio" value="option2"/>Green</label></li><li><div class=""><!-- BEGIN: ReCAPTCHA implementation example. --><div class="g-recaptcha" data-action="action" data-callback="onSuccess" data-sitekey="6Le-wvkSAAAAAPBMRTvw0Q4Muexq9bi0DJwx_mJ-" id="recaptcha-demo"><div style="width: 304px; height: 78px;"><div><iframe frameborder="0" height="78" name="a-hnna80f5ao1n" role="presentation" sandbox="allow-forms allow-popups allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-top-navigation allow-modals allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox" scrolling="no" src="https://google.com/recaptcha/api2/anchor?ar=1&amp;k=6Le-wvkSAAAAAPBMRTvw0Q4Muexq9bi0DJwx_mJ-&amp;co=aHR0cHM6Ly9nb29nbGUuY29tOjQ0Mw..&amp;hl=en&amp;v=MydHw_zggsxIJuhSbyOmPv5R&amp;size=normal&amp;sa=action&amp;cb=ai8083h1s1fb" title="reCAPTCHA" width="304"></iframe></div><textarea class="g-recaptcha-response" id="g-recaptcha-response" name="g-recaptcha-response" style="width: 250px; height: 40px; border: 1px solid rgb(193, 193, 193); margin: 10px 25px; padding: 0px; resize: none; display: none;"></textarea></div><iframe style="display: none;"></iframe></div><script nonce="">
                      var onSuccess = function(response) {
                        var errorDivs = document.getElementsByClassName("recaptcha-error");
                        if (errorDivs.length) {
                          errorDivs[0].className = "";
                        }
                        var errorMsgs = document.getElementsByClassName("recaptcha-error-message");
                        if (errorMsgs.length) {
                          errorMsgs[0].parentNode.removeChild(errorMsgs[0]);
                        }
                        };</script><!-- Optional noscript fallback. --><noscript><div style="width: 302px; height: 462px;"><iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="/recaptcha/api/fallback?k=6Le-wvkSAAAAAPBMRTvw0Q4Muexq9bi0DJwx_mJ-"></iframe><div><textarea class="g-recaptcha-response" id="g-recaptcha-response" name="g-recaptcha-response"></textarea></div></div><br/></noscript><!-- END: ReCAPTCHA implementation example. --></div></li><li><input id="recaptcha-demo-submit" type="submit" value="Submit"/></li></ul></fieldset></form></div><div style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 2px 2px 3px; position: absolute; transition: visibility 0s linear 0.3s, opacity 0.3s linear 0s; opacity: 0; visibility: hidden; z-index: 2000000000; left: 0px; top: -10000px;"><div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; position: fixed; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 2000000000; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); opacity: 0.05;"></div><div class="g-recaptcha-bubble-arrow" style="border: 11px solid transparent; width: 0px; height: 0px; position: absolute; pointer-events: none; margin-top: -11px; z-index: 2000000000;"></div><div class="g-recaptcha-bubble-arrow" style="border: 10px solid transparent; width: 0px; height: 0px; position: absolute; pointer-events: none; margin-top: -10px; z-index: 2000000000;"></div><div style="z-index: 2000000000; position: relative;"><iframe frameborder="0" name="c-hnna80f5ao1n" sandbox="allow-forms allow-popups allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-top-navigation allow-modals allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox" scrolling="no" src="https://google.com/recaptcha/api2/bframe?hl=en&amp;v=MydHw_zggsxIJuhSbyOmPv5R&amp;k=6Le-wvkSAAAAAPBMRTvw0Q4Muexq9bi0DJwx_mJ-" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" title="recaptcha challenge expires in two minutes"></iframe></div></div></body></html>
```

Any help will be appreciated :D

Comment: Can you confirm page URL?

Comment: this is the URL: https://google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo

Answer (score 0):

The element that you are finding is inside an `iframe`. To access elements in an `iframe` you must switch to it first. Use `driver.switch_to.frame` to switch frame

```py
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo")
delay = 5

try:
    driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[title="reCAPTCHA"]'))
    captcha = WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'recaptcha-checkbox-border'))
    )
    driver.switch_to.parent_frame()  # just to return outside

    print("Captcha is present in the DOM \n\n")
except TimeoutException:

    print("Captcha did not show up\n\n")
```

Comment: oh ok, i will try it. Thank you!